# OOP stuck on object design/naming

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I am designing a .NET tool that is using reflection to report information on methods inside our assemblies.

Its completely object oriented and made up of Assembly Objects, Class Objects and Method objects all with my defined information I am retrieving from reflection.
An Assembly contains many Classes and a class contains many Methods.

My problem is coming up with a structure and naming convention is is easy to read and use.

My current (rough example) object structure (in .NET) is just:

```
var assemblyList = new List<Assembly>();

public class Assembly
{
    public string Name;
    public List<Class> Classes;
}

public class Class {
    public string Name;
    public List<Method> Methods;
}

public class Method {
    public string Name;
}
```

This would work fine, except that I have additional properties that I want to have alongside each of these lists as im collecting information.
That and I have inner classes I want to have for these class definitions for example inside the Method class I may want to have a class I created called Types.

Would the below be appropriate (bear with me as its a rough representation, not the actual objects) or am I making too much of a mess of things. I can't think of a correct solution, but would expect there to be a simpler way of doing it.

```
public class Class {
        public class Context {
            public string Name;
            public List<Method.Context> Methods;
        }

        public class List {
            public List<Context> List;
            public string propertyA;
            public int propertyB;
        }

        public class Tags {
            public const string MethodTypeA = "Ex1";
            public const string MethodTypeB = "Ex2";
        }
    }

    public class Method
        public class Context {
            public string Name;
        }

        public class List {
            public List<Context> List;
            public string propertyA;
            public int propertyB;
        }

        public class Tags {
            public const string ClassTypeA = "Ex1";
            public const string ClassTypeB = "Ex2";
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated! My naming/structure design skills are quite poor.

Comment: Doesn't [`System.Reflection.Assembly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly(v=vs.110).aspx) already contain all this information?

Comment: Yeah it does, but theres a lot of filtering, logic and manipulation that is going to be built into my own objects and methods inside these objects so I have created separate classes to hold this information.

Comment: @Cyassin "Would the below be appropriate" Do you see any problems with it?

Comment: @Goyo I don't see any problems, but something just doesn't seem right with the structure.

Comment: "theres a lot of filtering, logic and manipulation that is going to be built into my own objects and methods"  It is unclear what you are trying to do. If it is indeed "to report information on methods inside our assemblies" you do not need anything over what System.Reflection offers. First define what  you want to report and in what format, then design an interface. I do not see  a need for state/data yet,  you just want a command that collect what it needs and returns a report. Even if you want to play with filters, there is nothing to persist, everything is already persisted in assemblies.

Comment: @Cyassin Something?

Comment: What are these classes intended to do?  Are you trying to build some View Models for a GUI application?     Have you considered the Layout, workflow and data which you want to include on your UI?   Do you know what information you want to be displayed in your reports?     Do you know how the Reflection data will be processed/filtered?   Have you captured a clear set of requirements/user stories for the app?     Do you have a target platform or UI framework for the app?

Comment: @Goyo you are telling me you have never written code that you have just thought hmmm its just not right...My instinct is in the future those objects are going to be hard to maintain if there is a lot more of them. What I have put as my question is a tiny part of the scope of the program.
If this place isn't for asking questions like this than let me know. But this isn't something that was just whipped up in a day. I'm sure no one wants to see the pages of documentation so thats why I have tried to dumb it down to my exact problem.

Comment: @MartinMaat If I need to make a large number of reports (which I do), its going to be slower to do the reflection on 2000 Dlls for each report and apply filtering, manipulation such as removing `1 from partial classes etc. each time. If I create my own restricted objects and did the filtering and manipulation once and then do each report, it will be much faster. My logic only wants public methods and has a large ignore list for classes/methods (still 800,000 public methods), I also want information on all their attributes, params etc. This question is a very subselect of a very large project.

Comment: @BenCottrell Its a console app with multiple outputs. One it will be a post build event in the nightly build to look for specific items to break the build. Secondly it will output HTML reports with statistics on the MVC entry points. So anything that is a public method inside an inherited controller class.
I have all doco'd the requirements, user stories etc. The question is just a  dumbed down specific problem to a larger project.

Comment: (many reports, performance) So, you start by solving a problem that likely does not exist because 1.OS read caching and 2.You are asleep when it runs, sure to create a lot of noise and room for errors. Get your logic straight first, and then, if you feel you need to speed it up, put some buffer in front of it that STILL does not have to be a class hierarchy but can be just a simple proxy object.

Comment: @MartinMaat While you raise a point that we will be asleep when it runs, I still cannot justify doing that. The filtering 1. Only captures public methods. 2. Removes about 1000 classes and 10,000 methods that are in our exclude list files. 3. Strips out unnecessary text such as `1 etc. Are you saying its worth doing all of that filtering at an output level and do it every report on 2000 DLL's and over 800,000 entry points.

Comment: @Cyassin I am saying you do not know if this is an issue yet and that you do not need your own class tree to trim down a couple of collections to just the items you are interested in. If the filtering would appear to be expensive you could try to speed it up or buffer some results but it seems to me you are not there yet and you are waisting your time on stuff that is somehow more appealing.

Comment: _it's a rough representation, not the actual objects_ are the names at least real?

Answer (score 1):

I assume You are going to have some meta information in your context. Right?

So potentially you might end up with a "God-Context" class, if You will, try to put different concepts under the same umbrella. For instance, in the following example there are two concepts mixed: usage and checksums.

```
someClassInstance.Context.ReferencedBy
someClassInstance.Context.MD5
someClassInstance.Context.SHA
```

So instead of having one context its better to split. Something like that:

```
someClassInstance.Usage.ReferencedBy
someClassInstance.Checksum.MD5
someClassInstance.Checksum.SHA
```

In some scenarios it migt be an overhead to introduce a class per concept, so you can easily combine names and expose the concepts via properties

```
someClassInstance.ReferencedBy
someClassInstance.MD5Checksum
someClassInstance.SHAChecksum
```

In your particular case it would be

```
 public class Class
 {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Method> Methods { get; set; } = new List<Method>();
        public List<Tag> Tags = new List<Tag>();

        ...
        public string SomeContextSpecificProperty1 { get; set; }
        ...
        public string SomeContextSpecificPropertyN { get; set; }
  }

  public class Method
  {
        public string Name;
        public List<Tag> Tags = new List<Tag>();
  }

  public class Tag
  {
      public string Value { get; set; }
  }
```

If You want to introduce class per context, consider this

```
public class Assembly
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Class> Classes { get; set; } = new List<Class>();
        public List<Tag> Tags = new List<Tag>();
        public AssemblyContext Context { get; set; }
        public class AssemblyContext
        {
            public string SomeContextSpecificProperty1 { get; set; }
            //,,,
            public string SomeContextSpecificPropertyN { get; set; }
        }
    }
```